# CORS Filter Error-- Need help to fix the same

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to create a javascript+html which actually performs the action like CSRF (Cross site request forgery). So far, I am able to do this.

```
<html> <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function logData() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open("POST", "https://example.com", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        xhr.send("data"); } </script> </head> <body>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit request" onclick="logData()" /> </body> </html>
```

When I am running this, I got the error like shown below:
"**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.**"

After a bit googling I came to know that this error s producing because of this reason:
". The reason is that there is what's called a preflight request before the actual request, which is an OPTIONS request. So the error comes from the fact that the preflight request doesn't produce the necessary headers"

SO, I have tried to add CORSFilter on the same code shown above. Honestly speaking, I don't have much good hands on javascript.

So, please let me know...how to add CORSfilter here..

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

It is the server that needs to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. Your server needs to include something like Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com.

Comment: What server are you using? You need to replace the example com domain with the domain from which the request is being generated. On a page from https://google.com to https://example.com the example.com server would need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://google.com

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your request is making a "preflight" OPTIONS request to the server to ask about CORS capabilities. Not only should your POST request handler send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header along with the response, but you should create an OPTIONS request handler that sends this header as well. There is more information [in this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) about the preflight OPTIONS request. You should be able to look in your inspector to see if the browser is making this preflight request or not. When I build the OPTIONS request handler, I usually respond with these headers (which can also be found in the MDN documentation I linked):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```